Meaning of inseparability degree
I was studying field theory when a question came to my mind.
Given a finite extension $L/K$, it is known that its degree is an upper bound for the degrees of the minimal polynomials of elements of $L$ over $K$ (being equal to the degree of its simple subextensions, and therefore dividing $[L:K]$).
My question is if there is something similar about the degree of separability or inseparability. For example, is is true that, given a minimal polynomial of an element of $L$ over $K$, its roots have multiplicity not greater than than the inseparability degree of $L$ over $K$? Are there any similar results in this fashion?

Yes, let $a\in L$ and let $f(x)$ be its minimal polynomial. Write $f(x) = g(x^{p^r})$ with $g$ separable and irreducible. So the multiplicity of the root $a$ of $f$ is $p^r$ Then consider the field tower $K(a) / K(a^{p^r}) / K$. The first extension is purely inseparable of degree $p^r$ and by multiplicativity of the inseparability index we have $p^r\leq[L:K]_i$, so the multiplicity of the root is at most the inseparability index. Also $K(a^{p^r})/K$ is separable of degree $\deg g$ which is the number of distinct roots of $f$ (in an algebraic closure), so similarly the separable degree $[L:K]_s$ is an upper bound for the number of distinct roots of the minimal polynomial.
